# Variable Lost after first Call

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So i am trying to code a UI based AK47 Card game, But i cannot for the love of god figure out why it lets me select the first round and after that undefines the variables. I am at such a loss. I think i might be defining something wrong in the Draw Class, since that is what makes up most of the action, but i addind the print("") so called debug messages, it shows that the corresponding cards are there and that the variable exists after it has finised its final action.

```
import time
import random
import tkinter as tk
suit = ["Club","Heart","Diamond","Spade"]
numb = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"]
junkHand = []
data = "true"

#The inital Drawing of 4 cards.
class drawCard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cardnr = []
        self.Hand = []
        self.card = []
        #looping until The ai and Player both have 4 cards.
        while(len(self.Hand) <= 3):
            self.cards = random.choice(suit)
            self.cardn = random.choice(numb)
            self.card = self.cards+" "+self.cardn

            if(self.card in self.Hand):
                #putind already drawn cards into the bad pile
                junkHand.append(self.card)
            else:
                junkHand.append(self.card)
                #appending the numbers of cards to card number Array.
                self.cardnr.append(self.cardn)
                #appending the cards to the hand Array.
                self.Hand.append(self.card)

playerHand = drawCard()
AIHand = drawCard()

#Discardng a useless card and drawing a new card.
class Draw:
    def __init__(self, choiceP, pHand, cardnr, data):
        self.card = []
        print(pHand)
        #poping out the chosen card.
        pHand.pop(int(choiceP)-1)
        cardnr.pop(int(choiceP)-1)

        while(len(pHand) <= 3):
            #generating a new card
            self.cards = random.choice(suit)
            self.cardn = random.choice(numb)
            #combining them
            self.card = self.cards+" "+self.cardn
            #Testing the cards
            if(self.card in junkHand):
                junkHand.append(self.card)
            else:
                junkHand.append(self.card)
                cardnr.append(self.cardn)
                pHand.append(self.card)
                print(pHand)
                
        #testing if the AI or Player moved.
        if(data == "false"):
            hand1Draw['file'] = 'data\\gif\\'+str(playerHand.Hand[0])+'.gif'
            hand2Draw['file'] = 'data\\gif\\'+str(playerHand.Hand[1])+'.gif'
            hand3Draw['file'] = 'data\\gif\\'+str(playerHand.Hand[2])+'.gif'
            hand4Draw['file'] = 'data\\gif\\'+str(playerHand.Hand[3])+'.gif'
            GameP2()
        elif(data == "true"):
            AIDraw()

def AIDraw():
    global numb, AIHand, data
    AISmort = []
    print(AISmort)

    #testing if the AIHand has any neccesary cards from AK47.
    if(numb[0] in AIHand.cardnr):
        AISmort.append(AIHand.cardnr.index(numb[0])+1)
    if(numb[3] in AIHand.cardnr):
        AISmort.append(AIHand.cardnr.index(numb[3])+1)
    if(numb[6] in AIHand.cardnr):
        AISmort.append(AIHand.cardnr.index(numb[6])+1)
    if(numb[12] in AIHand.cardnr):
        AISmort.append(AIHand.cardnr.index(numb[12])+1)

    rndChoiceAI = random.randint(1,4)
    if(rndChoiceAI in AISmort):
        print(AISmort)
        AIDraw()
    else:
        AISmort.clear()
        data = "false"
        AIHand = Draw(rndChoiceAI, AIHand.Hand, AIHand.cardnr, data)

def GameP2():
    global playerHand
    print("gameP2")
    print(playerHand.Hand)
    if(numb[0] in playerHand.cardnr):
        if(numb[3] in playerHand.cardnr):
            if(numb[6] in playerHand.cardnr):
                if(numb[12] in playerHand.cardnr):
                    print("you won the game :)")
                    time.sleep(10)
                    execfile('main.py')
                else: pass
            else: pass
        else: pass
    else: pass

    if(numb[0] in AIHand.cardnr):
        if(numb[3] in AIHand.cardnr):
            if(numb[6] in AIHand.cardnr):
                if(numb[12] in AIHand.cardnr):
                    print("you lost the game :(")
                    time.sleep(10)
                    execfile('main.py')
                else: pass
            else: pass
        else: pass
    else: print(playerHand.Hand)

def C1():
    global playerHand
    data = "true"
    choiceP = 1
    playerHand = Draw(choiceP, playerHand.Hand, playerHand.cardnr, data)
def C2():
    global playerHand
    data = "true"
    choiceP = 2
    playerHand = Draw(choiceP, playerHand.Hand, playerHand.cardnr, data)
def C3():
    global playerHand
    data = "true"
    choiceP = 3
    playerHand = Draw(choiceP, playerHand.Hand, playerHand.cardnr, data)
def C4():
    global playerHand
    data = "true"
    choiceP = 4
    playerHand = Draw(choiceP, playerHand.Hand, playerHand.cardnr, data)

cHeight = 768
cWidth = 1366

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Carlos' AK47")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=cHeight, width=cWidth)
canvas.pack()

TopFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#252525')
TopFrame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.05)

tableFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#639D5E')
tableFrame.place(rely=0.05, relwidth=1, relheight=0.95)

hand1Draw = tk.PhotoImage(file='data\\gif\\'+str(playerHand.Hand[0])+'.gif', master=tableFrame)
hand1Button = tk.Button(tableFrame, image=hand1Draw, relief='flat',command=C1)
hand1Button.place(relwidth=0.14, relheight=0.4, relx=0.2, rely=0.65)

hand2Draw = tk.PhotoImage(file='data\\gif\\'+str(playerHand.Hand[1])+'.gif', master=tableFrame)
hand2Button = tk.Button(tableFrame, image=hand2Draw, relief='flat',command=C2)
hand2Button.place(relwidth=0.14, relheight=0.4, relx=0.34, rely=0.65)

hand3Draw = tk.PhotoImage(file='data\\gif\\'+str(playerHand.Hand[2])+'.gif', master=tableFrame)
hand3Button = tk.Button(tableFrame, image=hand3Draw, relief='flat',command=C3)
hand3Button.place(relwidth=0.14, relheight=0.4, relx=0.48, rely=0.65)

hand4Draw = tk.PhotoImage(file='data\\gif\\'+str(playerHand.Hand[3])+'.gif', master=tableFrame)
hand4Button = tk.Button(tableFrame, image=hand4Draw, relief='flat',command=C4)
hand4Button.place(relwidth=0.14, relheight=0.4, relx=0.62, rely=0.65)

root.mainloop()
```

It worked perfectly without the UI, but once i added the UI. it threw up so many errors, most of which i fixed, but they brought up new errors. I.e. the cussent one.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Predator Backuo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__  
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Predator Backuo\Desktop\TLN Documents\Code\AK47\ak47.py", line 132, in C2
    playerHand = Draw(choiceP, playerHand.Hand, playerHand.cardnr, data)
AttributeError: 'Draw' object has no attribute 'Hand'        
PS C:\Users\Predator Backuo\Desktop\TLN Documents\Code\AK47>
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? i am not the best at python, i just do it out of hobby.

Comment: `playerHand` starts out as a `drawCard` object, but In your C1/C2/C3/C4 functions, you replace it with a `Draw` object, which does not have a `Hand` member.  Did you intend for `Draw` to be a function, and not a class?

Comment: Style complaints:  Those `else: pass` lines are useless and can be deleted.  `if` statements in Python do not need extra parentheses.  Remove them.  DO NOT use `execfile` to start a new instance of your app.  Instead, just reset your existing UI to its initial state and continue on.  `playerHand.Hand[0]` etc is already a string.  You don't need the `str()` conversion.

Comment: You seem to be using `class`es and `global`s in places where regular functions would be more appropriate.  (I'm guessing, but it looks like you might need to learn about the `return` keyword.)

Comment: Right.  You should really have a `Hand` class that holds all the cards for a single hand.  That class can have a "deal" function to deal a new hand, and a "draw" function to deal a new card.  The `Hand` object shouldn't care which hand it is.  That's up to the calling code.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think at one point i had another function in the Draw class, but i dropped it because it didn't work the way i intended. Also Thank you for your Style complaints. The If parenthesis i put for my own so called visual appeal. and everything else i am too begginner to know.
also, should i converst the draw class into a function and put it into the drawCard class?

Comment: Also, i just learned how to use Classes in python, and i'll be damned, i should've done it earlier. I've been just sitting behind VSCode and mainly writing code that calculates things. I like math, thats all i have to say.

Comment: A class is just a way to create objects.  An object is a THING.  It should have a set of RELATED data, and methods that allow access to that data in a controlled way.  "Draw" is a verb, not a noun, so it should be a function, not be a class.  A "Card" might be a class, a "Deck" might be a class containing cards (although that's not usually necessary), and a "Player" or "Hand" object would hold the cards for that hand.  You might have a "Game" object controlling everything.

Answer (score 0):

At first you are assigning a drawCard object to `playerHand = drawCard()`, which does contain a `Hand` attribute (line 13):

```
#The inital Drawing of 4 cards.
class drawCard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cardnr = []
        self.Hand = [] <--- the Hand attribute
        self.card = []
...

playerHand = drawCard() <-- add instance of this class to playerHand
```

But later on in the code (see your C functions), you are overwriting the `playerHand` variable with a `Draw` instance, which doesn't contain an attribute "Hand":

```
def C1():
    global playerHand
    data = "true"
    choiceP = 1
    playerHand = Draw(choiceP, playerHand.Hand, playerHand.cardnr, data) <-- add instance of another class to playerHand variable
```

Comment: Hej, thanks for the answer, I just learned Classes in python, and this is my first program that is actually using them. so i have literally no clue how they function with eachother. but as i read your answer i can see that classes cannot communicate with eachother.

Comment: @CarlosGross what do you mean by "communicate"? you can inherit from another class if that is what you meant, otherwise if you mean communicating between instances? well it is doable but there is no built-in method to send say a message from one class instance to another, but it is doable otherwise